# asp.net sqldatasource parameter not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, parameters, sqldatasource

I am creating a very simple CRUD (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) test program in asp.net framework 4 which needs to have  a table id as a uniqueidentifier and primary key. I have decided to let SQLServer create the unique identifier.

I need to get the delete stored procedure to work.

The program uses a SQLDatasource and FormView within a Webforms page which is accessed via stored procedures.

I can CREATE, READ AND UPDATE the data but NOT DELETE the data. I receive the following error when trying to delete:

"Procedure or function 'DeleteTestJobID' expects parameter '@TestJobID', which was not supplied."

I have included the Markup, Description, Exception, Source Error, Stack Trace as well as the SQLTable & Stored Procedures.

I have looked extensively for the last 48 hours within the MSDN site but cannot find a solution.

ASP.NET webforms page:

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="testjobSqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestJobSiteConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DeleteTestJobID" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        InsertCommand="AddTestJobID" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        SelectCommand="SelectAllTestJob" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateTestJob" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TestJobID" QueryStringField="TestJobID" 
               Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="testjobFormView1" Name="Name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TestJobID" QueryStringField="TestJobID" 
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="testjobFormView1" Name="Name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:FormView ID="testjobFormView1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="testjobSqlDataSource1">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            TestJobID:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TestJobIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("TestJobID") %>' />
            <br />
            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>

            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            TestJobID:
            <asp:Label ID="TestJobIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TestJobID") %>' />
            <br />
            Name:
            <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or
> function 'DeleteTestJobID' expects parameter '@TestJobID', which was
> not supplied.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'DeleteTestJobID'
> expects parameter '@TestJobID', which was not supplied.]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> +5352418    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
> ds) +1406
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
> completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
> Boolean asyncWrite) +205
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand
> command, DataSourceOperation operation) +380
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDelete(IDictionary
> keys, IDictionary oldValues) +568
> System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
> oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +84
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleDelete(String commandArg)
> +793    System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +519
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
> EventArgs e) +89    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
> source, EventArgs args) +37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
> EventArgs e) +80    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
> source, EventArgs args) +37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
> +121    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +10
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +9528682    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1724

### SQL Server

CREATE TABLE

```
USE [TestJobSite]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestJob]    Script Date: 28/06/2014 17:27:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestJob](
    [TestJobID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestJob] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestJob_TestJobID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [TestJobID]
GO
```

Stored procedure: DELETE

```
USE [TestJobSite]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeleteA]    Script Date: 27/06/2014 18:19:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteTestJobID]
        @TestJobID nchar(100)
        AS

        DELETE FROM
        TestJob
        WHERE
        TestJobID=@TestJobID

GO
```

Stored procedure: ADD ENTRY

```
USE [TestJobSite]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddAgency]    Script Date: 27/06/2014 18:02:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTestJobID]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @Name nchar(100)

        AS
        BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        INSERT INTO TestJob (Name)

        VALUES (@Name);
        END

GO
```

Stored procedure: READ

```
USE [TestJobSite]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SelectAllTestJob]    Script Date: 27/06/2014 18:22:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectAllTestJob]
        AS

        SELECT *  FROM
        TestJob

GO
```

Stored procedure: UPDATE

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateTestJob]    Script Date: 27/06/2014 18:24:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTestJob]
        @TestJobID nchar(100),
        @Name nchar(100)

        AS

        UPDATE TestJob
                    
        SET
        Name=@Name

        WHERE 
        TestJobID=@TestJobID;
GO
```

Comment: Is there query parameter called TestJobID in the query string of the url?

Comment: Yes, there is. The edit procedure works and reads the parameter from the URL. The delete somehow does not pick it up. I have tried manually writing it, copying it across from the edit parameters and even generating it from the sqldatasource configuation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the edit & delete function.

1. The edit function did not work! The reason was that the SELECT stored procedure was incorrect; it places the first record within the table. If you change the uniqueidentifier in the URL it always displays the first record within the table and then updates this the the content you enter inside the (name)textbox.

   To solve this simply change the select stored proc to this:

   ```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectTestJob]
            @TestJobID nchar(100)
            AS

            SELECT *  FROM
            TestJob
            WHERE
            TestJobID=@TestJobID
    GO
   ```

   This will select only one record from the table. Ensure that the markup within the sqldatasource looks like this now; pay attention to the SELECT statement and its type, then check the SELECT PARAMETER. The parameter must be a query string; as it is reading from the URL.

   ```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TestJobSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestJobSiteConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DeleteTestJob" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        InsertCommand="AddTestJobID" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        SelectCommand="SelectTestJob" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateTestJob" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TestJobID" QueryStringField="TestJobID" 
                Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="testjobFormView1" Name="Name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TestJobID" QueryStringField="TestJobID" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TestJobID" QueryStringField="TestJobID" 
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="testjobFormView1" Name="Name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
   ```
2. The DELETE procedure was not picking up the @TestJobID and I could not figure out until I checked the ItemTemplate within the FormView. There are 2 references (form label and URL); I simply removed the TestJobID displayed as a label within the form, saved and rebuilt and it worked! The amended form is now displayed below.

   > ```
   > <ItemTemplate>
   >     TestJobID:
   >
   >     <br />
   >     Name:
   >     <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
   >     <br />
   >     <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
   >         CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
   >     &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
   >         CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
   >     &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
   >         CommandName="New" Text="New" />
   > </ItemTemplate>
   > ```

Thank you Steve Wellens and StackOverflow for your assistance. I hope that this now working little CRUD test program is of use to asp.net developers who are keen to use uniqueidentifiers.